# Using return as one of multiple statements in ternary expression

Tags: javascript, ternary-operator

I have this code:

```
  err ? (reject(err), return)
      : resolve(db)
```

Which returns:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token return

However this works:

```
err ? (reject(err), console.log('test'))
    : resolve(db)
```

Why is that return can't be used in this situation? Is there other alternative to stop function execution while using ternary operator for multiple statements?

Comment: you can have only expressions. `return` is not part of expression

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a ternary *expression*, the expression as a whole must evaluate to a value, and thus contain only expressions.

You can't say `a = 1 + return;` either.

> Is there other alternative to stop function execution while using
>   ternary operator for multiple statements?

The `if` statement...

```
if (err) { reject(err); return }

resolve(db);
```

Comment: Oh I see, now I understand.

Answer (score 1):

```
err ? (reject(err), return)
    : resolve(db)
```

> Is there other alternative to stop function execution while using
>   ternary operator for multiple statements?

Ternary operators are not like `if else` in the sense of including an implicit `return` statement. So in order to return asap once the condition satisfies, you might properly do as follows.

```
return err ? reject(err)
           : resolve(db);
```

Comment: I only need return if err is true